# how to find file and run as source script?

Tags: bash, function, redeclare

I have folder with number of different files that contains functions.
I use declare to publish those functions to users.
This is sample function I use:

```
space () { 
 df -h
} 
declare -f space
```

Under user .bashrc I have added following:

```
for FILE in $HOME/functions/* ; do source $FILE ; done
```

However I get this message:

```
-bash: source: /home/user/functions/subdirectory: is a directory
```

Can anyone advise how to fix that or maybe there is better way to load functions to shell variables not to environment variables?

Comment: `…; do if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then source "$FILE"; fi; done`.

Comment: Sidenote: avoid using all caps for local variables like `FILE`, since it's supposed to be reserved for environment variables like `HOME` and special shell variables like `RANDOM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers and here is the update what works for me.

```
MYFUNC=$(find ~/functions -type f)
for f in $MYFUNC ; do
source $f > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

Just check if the file exists. Also, quote variable expansions. Prefer lower case variables.

```
for file in "$HOME"/functions/* ; do
     if [[ -f "$file" && -r "$file" ]]; then
        source "$file"
     fi
done
```

This is portable to posix shell (just change `[[` to `[` and `]]` to `]`) and is just usually written that way. I'm sure you'll find such loop in your `/etc/profile`. I've found some similar in [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L2360) script.

Answer (score 2):

I would correct xdhmoore's answer like this:

```
while read -d $'\0' file; do
    source "$file"
done < <(find $HOME/functions -type f -print0)
```

Indeed, using a pipe will prevent the current environment to be modified, which is one of the primary goal of the `source` command.

Example of the pipe problem: let's create the file `~/functions/fff` like this (and let's assume it's the only file into `~/functions`):

```
a=777
```

Then run `find ~/functions -type f | while read f; do source "$f"; done; echo $a`: you will have no output.

Then run `while read f; do source "$f"; done < <(find ~/functions -type f); echo $a`: you will have this output: `777`.

The reason of that behaviour is that a command piped with `|` is running in a subshell, then the *subshell environment* will be modified, not the current one.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I have experienced the subshell issue before but I always thought it was because I was using xargs. [Now I know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8k3bMiFVDQ&t=24s)